# Parse: Erase User Account and Session

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

When one deletes one's account, one's session should be deleted as well.

However the methods exposed by Parse to do this are mutually exclusive, such that:

```
PFUser.currentUser()?.deleteInBackground()
PFUser.logOut()
```

can't be called in parallel or in sequence, even with completion handlers.

How is this achieved, excluding Cloud Code?

Comment: did you ever find a solution

Comment: @kareem ended up rewriting in node

Comment: can u post the node code where it deletes the session?

Comment: ended up rewriting the app in node @kareem

Answer (score 0):

Please convert below code in Swift if necessary, it will works fine with me :

```
[[PFUser currentUser] deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded && !error) {
            [PFUser logOut];           
        }
        else
        {           
            NSLog(@"error: %@", error);           
        }
    }];
```

Hope It's work fine...

**Edit:** Converted code to Swift

```
PFUser.currentUser()?.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if succeeded {
        PFUser.logOut()
    }
    else {
        NSLog("error: \(error)")
    }
```